# Centos 7 Move file when new one is created

Tags: command-line, automation, centos, move

is there a way to move old file for example auto0 to another localisation when new one is created ?

I need something that move automatically created recording from game to my www folder so others can download it.

I dont want to lose any data due to move not saved file. So i want to wait for next match to be started.

Comment: Did something similiar with a filewatcher written in python. Would that work for you? Take a look here: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Assuming new file is being kept open, add ie. this line to crontab:

```
 $ for f in $(find /tmp/src -type f); do ! lsof $f &> /dev/null && mv $f /tmp/www ; done
```

test:

```
# from one terminal:
$ mkdir -p /tmp/{src,www} && touch /tmp/src/{one,two} && less /tmp/src/two


# execution shell: 
$ for f in $(find /tmp/src -type f); do ! lsof $f &> /dev/null && echo "mv $f /tmp/www" ; done

mv /tmp/src/one /tmp/www
```

If you just want to keep most recent (and new file is not actively opened), modify `find` to filter on time:

```
for f in $(find /tmp/src -type f -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort | awk '{print $2}' | head -n -1); do mv $f /tmp/www ; done
```